# Is there a way to identify in python if pandas data frame has been updated by code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a CSV file into pandas data frame. Once the data is in the data frame, I am building an inverted index on to it based on certain rules. I am caching this inverted index as I don't want to build it again and again from a performance point of view. But if the data changes in the data frame, I should be able to identify it and create a new inverted index. Is there a way to identify if data frame has changed or updated? I looked at at_time and between_time properties but I am not sure if those properties are right to use for this.

In database/file system we generally look at the metadata - timestamp and identify if the file is updated or not. This is my first python project and I am looking for some suggestions as to how I can implement this.

Comment: With a dataframe, you control it within you're code.  It's not a shared table in a database.  Unless you are accessing the data from a database, hdfstore, or csv (which you stated) and you're asking if there is a way to detect if the csv has been updated.  Or, are you really asking if there is a way to detect if the dataframe in your code has been updated?  I just reread my comment and I sound condescending.  I don't mean to be.  I am just trying to get clarification.

Comment: @piRSquared - Thanks for asking. My question is to know if there is a way to detect if the data frame in your code has been updated or not.

Comment: What about hashing the underlying numpy array? Or subclassing the data frame class and add a flag each time the data gets modifiied

Comment: Do you mean caching or pickling?

Comment: @Edu - We thought about hashing but it will again require whole table scan but the other idea of subclassing the data frame class looks good and I will see if that can work for my case.